# Running Ollie example in java

Tags: java, scala, maven

I am trying to run the java example of Ollie (source code provided [here](https://github.com/knowitall/ollie/blob/master/example/src/main/java/example/JavaOllieWrapper.java))

I have created a maven project and imported all the required jars. There is no compile time error. When I run this program, I get following exception

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/convert/WrapAsScala`

This happens when I try to load MaltParser.
I have scala 2.9.2 and java 1.8.0_40 installed.

Comment: How do you want to run that? Do you have correct CLASS_PATH? Do you use SBT or Maven?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE for all these. I have created a maven project and running that as a java application.